# How to create a fake class from scratch with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I currently need to test a method that checks a class for the existance of a supplied method with PHPUnit.

Currently I simply create an empty class inside my unit test and it works fine. I am guessing there is probably a better solution though. This is the code that I am currently running:

```
class ControllerMiddleWareTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * Check to see if a faulty method name leads to a MethodNotFoundException.
     */
    public function testShouldMethodNotFoundException()
    {
        $this->expectException(MethodNotFoundException::class);

        $parameterBag = new Bag(['lang' => 'NL']);

        // This class name(and method) should never exist.
        new ControllerMiddleware('AwesomeController', 'init', $parameterBag);
    }
}

// Mock class so we get a MethodNotFoundException.
class AwesomeController{}
```

I have found plenty of examples where an existing class is being mocked but not where a class is created like this. How would I go about doing this properly?

Comment: this [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/all-about-mocking-with-phpunit--net-27252) might help

Comment: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs

Comment: Thanks, I followed the tutorial and this works fine: $this->getMockBuilder('AwesomeController')->getMock();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
$this->getMockBuilder('AwesomeController')->getMock();
```

If anybody else knows a better way or has any suggestions, I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: `$this->createMock(AwesomeController::class)` would be the best practice.